# NPE in line invoking equals()

Tags: java, class, methods, equals

Sorry if this all seems hard to understand but I am new to programming and I have looked in several books and websites and from my understanding what I am trying to do should work. The assignment I am working on is classes calling classes. Without putting all my code in here I will try to be as specific as possible in unclear areas. The null pointer exception is for this particular line of code:

```
  if(CDList[i].getArtist().equals(artist) == true)
```

//CDList is an array of CD objects (which are created in another class)

//getArtist() is a method of the CD class which returns a String

//the artist in the equals() is the Scanner object the user has inputed, also a String

The point of this particular method is to search through the array CDList and compare the artist String stored to the artist String scanned in and then the same for the title. If found then the contents of that portion of the array will be deleted. Here is the rest of the method if it will help:

```
void delete()
{
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter artist and title to be deleted: ");
   String artist = input.nextLine();
   String title = input.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i <= numOfCDs; i++)
{
   if(CDList[i].getArtist().equals(artist) == true)
   {
      for(int j = 0; j <= numOfCDs; j++)
      {
         if(CDList[j].getTitle().equals(title) == true)
         {
            System.out.println("Found CD: " + CDList[j].getArtist() + " " +                 
               CDList[j].getTitle());
            System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Y/1 N/0 ");

        if(input.nextInt() == 1)
            {
               CDList[j] = null;
               numOfCDs--;
            }
         }
         else
            System.out.println("CD not found.");
      }
    }
    else
       System.out.println("CD not found.");
 }
}
```

Sorry, here is the rest of the code. Just thought it was so much I'd leave it out.

CD Class:

```
package assignment3;
public class CD 
{
    public String artist;
    public String title;
    private tracklist listOfTracks = new tracklist();

CD(String artistName, String titleName)
{
    artist = artistName;
    title = titleName;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public String getTitle()
{
     return title;
}

public boolean addTrack(String trackInfo)
{
     boolean result = false;
     if(listOfTracks.add(trackInfo) == true)
         result = true;
     return result;
}

public int numTracks()
{
    int count = listOfTracks.count();
    return count;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(getArtist() + " : " + getTitle());
    listOfTracks.display(7);
}
}
```

trackList Class:

```
package assignment3;
public class tracklist 
{
    public String[] tracks;
    public int numElements;

    tracklist()
    {
        tracks = new String[99];
        numElements = 0;
    }

    public boolean add(String track)
    {
        boolean result = true;
        int index = 0;

        while(tracks[index] != null)
        {
           index++;
        }    

        tracks[index] = track;
        numElements++;
        if(numElements > 99)
            result = false;
        return result;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        return numElements;
    }

    public void display(int indent)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(i);
            if(i >= 10)
            {
                 for(int j = 0; j < (indent - 1); j++)
                 {
                     System.out.print(" ");
                 }
            } 
            else
            {
                 for(int j = 0; j < indent; j++)
                 {
                     System.out.print(" ");
                 }
            }
            System.out.println(tracks[i]);
         }
    }    
   }
```

CDList Class:

```
package assignment3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CDList 
{
   public int numOfCDs;
   private CD[] CDList;
   private int front,rear;

   CDList(int size)
   {
       CDList = new CD[size];
       numOfCDs = 0;
       front = 0;
       rear = size - 1;
   } 

   boolean add()
   {
       boolean result;
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter the Artist Name and CD Title: ");
       CD userCD = new CD(input.nextLine(), input.nextLine());
       System.out.println("Enter the number of tracks: ");
       int trackNumber = input.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Enter your track titles: ");

       for(int i = 0; i <= trackNumber; i++)
       {
           userCD.addTrack(input.nextLine());
       }

       if(rear == front)
           result = false;
       else
       {
           if(CDList[rear] != null)
           rear--;
           else
               CDList[rear] = userCD;
           result = true;
       }
       return result;
   }

   void delete()
   {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter artist and title to be deleted: ");
       String artist = input.nextLine();
       String title = input.nextLine();

       for(int i = 0; i <= CDList.length - 1; i++)
       {
           if((CDList[i].getArtist().equals(artist)) &&    
             (CDList[i].getTitle().equals(title)))
           {
               System.out.println("Found CD of: " + CDList[i].getArtist() + " " +                 
                 CDList[i].getTitle());
               System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Y/1 N/0 ");
               if(input.nextInt() == 1)
               {
                   CDList[i] = null;
                   numOfCDs--;
               }
           }
           else
               System.out.println("CD not found.");
       }
   }

   void SortArtist()
   {
       CD temp = new CD(" ", " ");
       for(int i = 0; i < numOfCDs; i++)
           if(CDList[i].getArtist().compareTo(CDList[i + 1].getArtist()) < 0)
           {
               temp = CDList[i];
               CDList[i] = CDList[i + 1];
               CDList[i + 1] = temp;
           }
   }

   void SortTitle()
   {
       CD temp = new CD(" ", " ");
       for(int i = numOfCDs; i > 0; i--)
       {
           int x = 0;
           for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
           {
               if(CDList[i].getTitle().compareTo(CDList[i + 1].getTitle()) < 0)
                   x = j;
           }
           temp = CDList[x];
           CDList[x] = CDList[i];
           CDList[i] = temp;
       }
   }

   void Display()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i <= numOfCDs; i++)
      {
          while(CDList[i] == null)
              i++;
          CDList[i].display();
      }
   }

   int size()
   {
       return numOfCDs;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `if (contition == true)` just use `if (condition)`.

Comment: You don't need the `== true` at all.

Comment: Please provide some example input and output.

Comment: How many items are in CDList?

Comment: Can you please add the CD class code.

Answer (score 4):

```
if(CDList[i].getArtist().equals(artist) == true)
```

If you are getting NPE, here are the possibilities:

1. `CDList` is null
2. `CDList[i]` is null
3. `CDLIst[i].getArtist()` returns null
4. Class `Artist` overrides `equals()` and has a bug that results in NPE, but in that case the NPE would point to a statement in `equals()`.

You haven't shown the class `Artist` so we can see if it overrides `equals()`, and haven't posted the stack trace so we can see exactly where the exception is thrown.

As others have commented, the `== true` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `LinkedList<CD>` or `ArrayList<CD>` instead of `CD[]`.

This will allow you to easily remove items, like so:

```
LinkedList<CD> cdList = new LinkedList<CD>();
// add items with cdList.add(...);
Iterator<CD> cdListIterator = cdList.iterator();

// Loop while the list still contains elements.
while (cdListIterator.hasNext()) {
    CD thisCd = iterator.next();
    // do some operation on the cd to tell whether you want to delete it
    // for example:
    if (thisCd.getArtist().equals(artist) && thisCd.getTitle().equals(title)) {
        iterator.remove(); // it's that simple
        // Don't have to mess with `cdCount--` or anything.
    }
}
```

And, as some have commented, you don't need `a.equals(b) == true`; you can just use `a.equals(b)`.

Comment: @user2159150: glad to hear you found it. As a final note, consider renaming your variable `CDList` to `cdList`; in Java, by convention, classes start with CapitalLetters (e.g., `String`, `CD`, `File`), and variable names (e.g., `frame`, `args`, `button`) are written in camelCase. This will make your code easier to understand by other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing wrong with if condition. Its your loop that has the problem.
Use a single for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= numOfCDs; i++)
{
   if(CDList[i].getArtist().equals(artist) && CDList[i].getTitle().equals(title))
   {
       System.out.println("Found CD: " + CDList[j].getArtist() + " " + CDList[j].getTitle());
       System.out.println("Would you like to delete it? Y/1 N/0 ");
       if(input.nextInt() == 1)
            {
               CDList[i] = null;
               // do not do numOfCDs-- here
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here.

The immediate cause of your NPE is that the inner loop "removes" a CD from the list by assigning it to `null`, and then the outer loop tries to test the CD at the position you just removed.  Since it is `null`, you then attempt to call `null.getArtist()` which NPEs.

The first thing to note is that you only need one loop.  The loop body should test that the CD you are looking at has the same title AND artist ...

The next thing to note is that getting rid of the extra loop is not enough.  If the `delete()` method is called more than once, the second call is likely to encounter a `null` entry that was produced by the first call ... and you will get an NPE as before.  The tests should check for a `null` before they try to get the title / artist information; e.g.

```
CD cd = cdList[i];
if (cd != null && 
    cd.getArtist().equals(artist) &&
    cd.getTitle().equals(title)) {
    // ...
}
```

At this point a design problem becomes apparent.  These `null` values in the array are a **bad idea**.  There are three fixes:

- You could remove the CDs by creating a new array one element smaller ... and copy across all CDs apart from the one you are deleting.
- You could add a `cdListSize` field, and arrange that it gives you the number of valid entries in the list.  Then (and this is the important bit), when you delete an entry from the list, move the current last entry to the place where the deleted entry was and decrement the `cdListSize`.  If you do that consistently, the `null` entries will all be at the end, and you can iterate from zero to `cdListSize - 1` to get the non-null entries.
- Best of all, use a `List` rather than an array to represent the CD list.  The `List` API provides a method for removing the entry at a given position.  The method *really* removes it ... it doesn't just set it to `null`.

Finally, you may need to take a step back and look at the larger application.  Is the CD list supposed to be persisted; e.g. so that it is still available when your application restarts?  Is it likely to be large; e.g. too large to fit into memory?  Are you likely to want to do complicated queries on the CD list?  All of these things would suggest that you should use a database rather than an in-memory data structure.

(However, with the extra code you've just added, it is clear that would be beyond the scope of your assignment.)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Thank ya'll for your comments, I did make some changes that ya'll recommended. The issue was with the CDList[i] being null. Just implemented a if(CDList[i] == null) then continue; Thank ya'll for your input. –